# File Getting Corrupted after upload node FS

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, electron, filereader

Hi i am using html5 filereader and node fs to upload the file to server which i am able to do so far, but the result file is larger than the original one.
here is my code.

```
var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0],
    r = new FileReader();
console.log(f); //for checking file info
r.onloadend = function(e) {
    var data = e.target.result;
    var fs = require('fs');
    try {
        fs.writeFileSync(f.name, data, 'utf-8');
        console.log('saved sucessfully!');
    } catch (e) {
        alert('Failed to save the file !');
    }
}

r.readAsBinaryString(f);
}
```

Comment: `readAsBinaryString` is deprecated. I am not used to browserify (that you use right?) but can't `fs` methods accept directly the Blob object, or an ArrayBuffer?

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. i am using node with electronjs btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work. I had to just convert data as ArrayBuffer

here is my final working code:

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0],
        r = new FileReader();
    // console.log('srcPath='+f.path);
    // console.log('savPath='+f.name);

    r.onloadend = function(e) {
        var data = e.target.result;
        try {
            fs.writeFileSync('uploads/' + f.name, Buffer.from(new Uint8Array(this.result)));
            console.log('saved sucessfully!');
        } catch (e) {
            alert('Failed to save the file !');
        }
        //send your binary data via $http or $resource or do anything else with it
    }

    r.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
    console.log('binary=' + r);
```